# How can call a function from a model that binding for delegate of the model on the delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I design a model which can have `UIPopoverController` on iPhone . The model have a delegate (`UIViewController` class) , I binding a function that  add an  `UITapGestureRecognizer`  for delegate in the model, How can I init the model and call the function.

I can do that  because I found Xcode called a same name function in delegate  not called the function in model;

Here is some code:

```
if ([self isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
{
    UIViewController *presentViewController = (UIViewController*)self.delegate;

    [presentViewController.view addSubview:INviewController.view];

    [self addGesture]
}

self.tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(test)];
```

Comment: Sorry,it is I can't do that because I found Xcode called a same name function in delegate not called the function in model,

Comment: Hi, are you trying to detect if you tap on ViewController2 and send a message to ViewController1 which presented ViewController2?

Comment: I have a ViewController and the ViewController is a delegate of a model,I want to tap on ViewController that response a function in model.        @quantumpotato

Comment: Can you post some code please of how you are implementing your delegate? If the view controller is the delegate of a model, then the model sends messages to the view controller. If you want tapping on the viewcontroller to send messages to the model then you need a reference to the model on your view controller. Please paste your code!

Comment: Also, your first line -- checking if you are a ViewController or not -- seems unneccessary. If you're making this code in a ViewController that will always be true.

Comment: I made it last night,but I think that will have some problem,I used keyWindow,the code is not perfect .Because I really don't know how to operate this website so tell me your email , I send my demo to you and tell me where will have problem in code.       @quantumpotato

Comment: It's my username here at gmail